# Right-click "Edit" is missing for .bat files

Tags: windows, batch, windows-registry, right-click

When I right click on a batch file, the Edit option that opens it in Notepad is not there.  How do I get it back?

Answer (score 1):

That's a context menu issue. Try [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-open-with-notepad-to-the-context-menu-for-all-files/).

Answer (score 0):

If that file is marked as read-only, then that'd make sense for that to be missing.

Right-click the file and select "Properties". Make sure it's not marked as "Read-Only". I guess that "Archive" property may also cause this, not sure what that really does, actually.

If that's not it, you could always try opening the file directly from Notepad. Start > Run > notepad. Then open that file, edit it, save it. You may have better luck yet, if you make a copy of the file first.

**Edit: Here's how to manually add the edit option**

1. Open Windows Explorer, click on Tools > Folder Options
2. Click on the File Types tab
3. Click "new" to add a file type, type in "bat" as the extension. Make sure the associated file type list is correctly set.
4. Select the new association you've made, and add a new action for editing.

Comment: The file is not read-only.  I can open it from within Notepad. But how to I get that "Edit" option back??

Comment: If you cut & paste the contents in to a new batch file stored in your My Docs, can you "edit" that? Is it possible your file extensions aren't actually .bat, but rather .bat.txt or something?

Comment: No. Every single batch file, old and new, is missing the Right-Click edit option.  And I know they are actual batch files.  If I double click them, they run like batch files.

Comment: Are you selecting more than one file to edit at one time?....http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/131470-context-menu-items-missing-fix-when-more-than-15-files-selected.html